# Using predictNLS to create confidence intervals around fitted values in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, nls, modelr

I want to build confidence intervals around a large set of fitted values using predictNLS from the propogate package in R. As an example, I will use the data set they reference in the function description (https://rdrr.io/github/anspiess/propagate/man/predictNLS.html), DNase, and building a model that takes the values conc and density as features:

```
library(propogate)
library(dplyr)
library(modelr)

DNase <- DNase

modeldna <- DNase %>% group_by(Run) %>% 
  do(run_model = nls(density ~ a * exp(b * conc), 
start = list(a = 1 , b = 0.5), 
data = .)) %>% ungroup()
```

I then want to give each row the model that it is assigned to so that predictions can be added:

```
DNApredict <- full_join(as_tibble(DNase), modeldna, by = "Run")
```

Add in the predictions:

```
DNApredict <- DNApredict %>% 
  group_by(Run) %>% 
  do(add_predictions(., var = "predicted_density", first(.$run_model)))
```

And then, I want to add the confidence interval data that predictNLS seems to provide, by giving it that same data and asking it to give a confidence interval for each fitted point in the predicted_density column:

```
confidence_interval <- predictNLS(model = modeldna, newdata = DNApredict$predicted_density, interval = "confidence")
```

However, the following error arises:

> Error in as.list(object$call$formula) :
> argument "object" is missing, with no default

Does anyone know what might be causing this? I know that it will likely seem obvious to some of you what the object it is calling is, so I apologize if this is a ridiculous question. I am really hoping to be able to use this function to create confidence intervals around a series of fitted values. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I think the objects you are passing to the predictNLS function are not what it expects. The first variable is a straight model returned by the nls function, and the second is a dataframe with new predictor values and the same column names as the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are running an `nls` on each `Run` in the sample data set, it is easy to get a list of nls models by splitting each run into its own data frame, and running `nls` on each data frame using `lapply`

```r
library(propagate)

DNase <- DNase

modeldna <- DNase %>% split(DNase$Run)

models <- lapply(modeldna, function(d) nls(density ~ a * exp(b * conc), 
                                           start = list(a = 1 , b = 0.5), 
                                           data = d))
```

Now we can get predictions for each point in each model just as easily by running `predictNLS` on each model (again inside `lapply`)

```r
results <- lapply(seq_along(modeldna), function(i) {
 predictNLS(models[[i]], newdata = data.frame(conc = modeldna[[i]]$conc))
})
```

Because of the output structure of `predictNLS`, we need to extract the predictions for each row and coerce them into a data frame:

```r
predictions <- lapply(results, function(x) {
  as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(x$prop, function(y) y$prop)))})
```

Finally, we can stick our predictions (including confidence intervals) back onto the original data frame:

```r
all_results <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(modeldna), 
                      function(i) cbind(modeldna[[i]], predictions[[i]])))
```

This now gives us a complete data frame of original data points, and the relevant predictions with confidence intervals.

To show this, we can plot the results in `ggplot`. Here we show one plot for each run, including its original data, the predicted value as a dotted line, and the 95% confidence limit as a pale blue ribbon:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(all_results, aes(x = conc, y = density)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = `2.5%`, ymax = `97.5%`), 
              fill = "deepskyblue4", alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(y = Mean.1), linetype = 2) +
  facet_wrap(.~factor(Run, levels = 1:11)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow what a clear explanation, thank you so much Allan! Was just looking into lapply() as a possible option and your process makes it so much clearer.